# I'm trying to get the output from my model,but got 4 tensor.I dont know anything about these tensors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get the output from my model,but got 4 tensor.I dont know anything about these tensors
i use the model to detect face.
Here is my model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkG4k.png)

The model's input is frame of Webcam ,Here is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfsZU.png)

here are my code

```
      const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(video)
      let resized = img;
      if (img.shape[0] !== 640 || img.shape[1] !== 640) {
        const alignCorners = true;
        resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
          img, [640, 640], alignCorners,
        );
      }

      // 
      const batched = resized.reshape([-1, 640, 640, 3]);

      // console.log(batched)
      const obj = await net.executeAsync(batched);
      console.log(obj);
```

Comment: sorry ,i need to correct a mistake
const batched = resized.reshape([-1, 640, 640, 3]);

Comment: Have you tried https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.dataSync ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the tensor data, you can use the [dataSync](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.dataSync) method  which is the synchronous version of [data](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.data)